# Change background color of children rows based on their indent level in Ant design Table

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant Design Table to display tree data. What I need to do is to color each level of indent differently to make it easier to distinguish.

Below is an example of how I'd want to style each row.

```
- Parent 1 (White)
   - Child 1 (Grey)
   - Child 2 (Grey)
      - Child 1 (Darker grey)
          - Child 1 (Even darker grey)
   - Child 3 (Grey)
       - Child 1 (Darker grey)

- Parent 2 (White)
   - Child 1 (Grey)
```

Please take a look at Ant Designs' example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/4xmpr1?file=/demo.js

I have tried to use this property:

```
expandable= {{
  expandedRowClassName: (record, index, indent) => {
  ....
  }
}}
```

But Ant Design does not seem to call this function when using tree data, only if you have set the `rowExpandable` property to true. But in the case of tree data they arent 'expandable' in this sense so its not calling the function.

Has anyone done this before?